# Publishing built html files with github

Tags: github, gulp, github-pages

I have a file `src/test/html/index.html` that first needs to be compiled to `target/test/html/index.html` and at this point I want it to be the project page for the repository.

I have a gulp task that is responsible for performing the build at the root of the repository.  The command that performs the build is `gulp build:css && gulp test:css`.  Once that's done it creates the `target/test/html/index.html`.

Is there a way to both perform the build on github and tell github to use the built page `target/test/html/index.html` as the `gh-pages` home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a build Server to perform that Task. In one of the Projects I am contributing to we are using travis to build a Webpage. In our case the Story is a Little bit more complex because I wanted travis to create a pull-request containing the latest changes instead of commiting the files instantly.

You can see the code I build some months ago to perform that Task l.60ff. [here](https://github.com/serious6/ews-java-api/blob/8e1869d9d867349fa781c7f9ce78fb67c8977558/deploy_snapshot.sh#L60). You will also Need to create a technical user that will be able to push changes to your repository. Travis provides ways to encrypt the stored credentials.